# ambiguity with environmental variables in windows

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat7

i am relatively new to java. when i installed jdk and jre on my laptop it asked me to set a system variable with the name **path and a value of its home directory**. next i installed tomcat server and that too asked me to set CATALINA_HOME,JAVA_HOME and **path as its home directory**.now after mysql installation it also said a variable of **path with its home directory value**.will it not effect the old s/w if i change path variable to new software variable address?? or should i create new paths for each software??

Answer (score 1):

`CATALINA_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` are separate variables and should be set separately.

As for the `PATH`, this is one variable and should contain all necessary values separated by the `;` character.